# How to search for App Maker files on Google Drive UI?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-app-maker

App Maker apps created directly from the App Maker app (https://appmaker.google.com) or from Google Drive by clicking on New button, then on More > Google App Maker are listed on **My Unit**, **Recent** and when they are created by others and shared with me on **Shared with me**. What I'm looking for is to use the `type` search operator on the Google Drive UI to find all my/shared with me App Maker apps.

Contrary as occurs with other file types, App Maker type it's not listed on the Advanced Search file type dropdown as it happens with Google Apps Script standalone projects but with this kind of files we could use `type:script`

I already tried:

- [type:appmaker](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:appmaker)
- [type:app-maker](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:app-maker)
- [type:googleappmaker](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:googleappmaker)
- [type:google-app-maker](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:google-app-maker)

I already know that I could use the Google Drive Advanced Service / API to search files by using the Mime Type (`application/vnd.google-apps.appmaker`) but I would like to do this directly from the Google Drive UI. Is this possible?

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type
  NOTE: The Mime Type for App Maker isn't included here.
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types
  NOTE: The Mime Type for App Maker isn't included here either, but it's shown when on mouse over on the info panel of a App Maker file on Google Drive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is realted to Google Drive UI usage instead of Google App Maker usage.

Comment: @Morfinismo Google Drive is a tool used by (Google App Maker, Google Apps Script and other) developers. Questions about tools commonly used by developers are on-topic according to [help/on-topic].

Comment: I understand your point. Sorry if we don't feel the same way, I just feel this is geared towards more the usage of Google Drive UI and not App Maker itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an appmaker question, however to answer your question directly... you can use this on the search bar:

```
app:"Google App Maker"
```

Reference: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en